# Flutter Grid View image and tilte

Tags: flutter, gridview

Hi I am creating a flutter screen as follow.

I want to add name under image. If I add column, image is shrink.

May I know how I can add the artist name under image.

Here is the code that I have created for following screen

```
Widget buidArtistScreen(BuildContext context, List<Artist> artists) =>
  GridView.builder(
    itemCount: artists.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) => buidImageCard(index, artists[index]),
    gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
      crossAxisCount: 2,
      mainAxisSpacing: 8,
      crossAxisSpacing: 8,
    ),
  );

Widget buidImageCard(int index, Artist artist) => Card(
    margin: EdgeInsets.zero,
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
    ),
    child: Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
      child: ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
              image: NetworkImage(artist.profilePicture),
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
          ),
          child: Align(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
            child: Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.all(4),
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100)),
              child: const Icon(
                Icons.play_arrow,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
```

[image]

Here is the code with artist name

```
Widget buidImageCard(int index, Artist artist) => Card(
    margin: EdgeInsets.zero,
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
    ),
    child: Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
      child: Column(
        children: [
          ClipRRect(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                image: DecorationImage(
                  image: NetworkImage(artist.profilePicture),
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
              ),
              child: Align(
                alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                child: Container(
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.all(4),
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100)),
                  child: const Icon(
                    Icons.play_arrow,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 20,),
          Text(artist.name)
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is how I achieved. Added Expanded.

```
Widget buildImageCard(int index, Artist artist) => Card(
    clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
    margin: EdgeInsets.zero,
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
    ),
    child: GestureDetector(
      onTap: () => Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => AlbumScreen(artist: artist),
        ),
      ),
      child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  image: DecorationImage(
                    image: NetworkImage(artist.profilePicture),
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  ),
                ),
                child: Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                  child: Container(
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                    //padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100)),
                    child: const Icon(
                      Icons.play_arrow,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Text(artist.name),
            )
          ]),
    ),
  );
```